# Create a json object storing only value in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json

I have to store an object in my AngularJS code. The values that are to be stored are variables that are passed in a function that is called when a button is clicked.

The basic structure of the object is :

```
"TopNode" : {
    "CreateNode" : {
        "ChildNode": {
            "LowestNodeOne": "LowestNodeTwo"
        }
    }
}
```

All the above variables are obtained from the function parameters. But the problem here is that when I write the variables in the above object, i.e

```
variableTop : {
    variableCreate : {
        variableChild : {
            variableLowOne : "Value for LowestNodeTwo"
        }
    }
}
```

But this code return the variable name itself and not the value stored in it *(except for the lowest value variable)*.

I'm also fine with storing the object as a key-value pair, where the name of the key would also be stored along with its value. But I'm not sure exactly how would the structure of such an object would be?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: so you are taking vars and making a json object from all of it , if im not wrong ?

Comment: Can you share your code please. Not able to understand the question from the given explanation

Answer (score 0):

Not able to understand the first version of the problem .
Will Edit this answer if i get hold of the problem.

But for your second part of the problem , you can store JSON key value pairs in Hash map like this:

```
[parent] = parent.child1
[parent.child1] = parent.child1.child
[parent.child1.child] = value
```

Algo - Traverse map till a value of a key is not a key .

Note : Hash maps and JSON have their own use cases . Usage  of Hash Maps as a hierarchical object is not recommended as if the number of child nodes increase there would be a performance hit while traversing to the desired node , Better you go with JSON approach.